# HMRC VAT (MTD) Test API: 404 "MATCHING_RESOURCE_NOT_FOUND"

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm trying to POST test VAT data to the "/organisations/vat/{vrn}/returns" endpoint. I'm able to grant authorisation using a test organisation login, however after doing so the following code keeps returning: "code": "MATCHING_RESOURCE_NOT_FOUND" Anyone have an idea why? I've tried to adjust the headers but I keep getting back the same message. I'm wondering if HMRC doesn't enable us to POST data to a test user?

```
var CLIENT_ID = 'thQadHpQDi52iVxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';
var CLIENT_SECRET = '702b5465-4a2b-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxx';


// Authorizes and makes a request to the HMRC API //

function run() {
//getService().reset();
  var service = getService();
  if (service.hasAccess()) {
    var url = 'https://test-api.service.hmrc.gov.uk/organisations/vat/766434212/returns';
    var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, {
      headers: {
        Accept : 'application/vnd.hmrc.1.0+json',
        Authorization: 'Bearer ' + service.getAccessToken(),
        ContentType: 'application/json',
        Scope: 'write:vat'
      }});
    var result = JSON.parse(response.getContentText());
    Logger.log(JSON.stringify(result, null, 2));

// POST VAT Test Data //

    var vatData = {
      'grant_type': 'client_credentials',
      'client_secret' : CLIENT_SECRET,
      'client_id': CLIENT_ID,
      'periodKey': '18A2',
      'vatDueSales': 105.50,
      'vatDueAcquisitions': -100.45,
      'totalVatDue': 5.05,
      'vatReclaimedCurrPeriod': 105.15,
      'netVatDue': 100.10,
      'totalValueSalesExVAT': 300,
      'totalValuePurchasesExVAT': 300,
      'totalValueGoodsSuppliedExVAT': 3000,
      'totalAcquisitionsExVAT': 3000,
      'finalised': true
    };

    var options = {
      'Accept' : 'application/vnd.hmrc.1.0+json',
      'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + service.getAccessToken(),
      'method' : 'POST',
      'contentType': 'application/json',
      'payload' : vatData,
      'gov-test-scenario': 'QUARTERLY_NONE_MET'
    };

UrlFetchApp.fetch('https://test-api.service.hmrc.gov.uk/organisations/vat/766434212/returns', options);
  } else {
    var authorizationUrl = service.getAuthorizationUrl();
    Logger.log('%s',authorizationUrl);
  }
}

// Configure the service //

function getService() {
  return OAuth2.createService('oAuth Testing')
    // Set the endpoint URLs.
      .setAuthorizationBaseUrl('https://test-api.service.hmrc.gov.uk/oauth/authorize')
      .setTokenUrl('https://test-api.service.hmrc.gov.uk/oauth/token')
      .setClientId(CLIENT_ID)
      .setClientSecret(CLIENT_SECRET)
      .setCallbackFunction('authCallback')
      .setPropertyStore(PropertiesService.getUserProperties())
      .setScope('write:vat')
}


// Auth Callback //

function authCallback(request) {
  var service = getService();
  var authorized = service.handleCallback(request);
  if (authorized) {
    return HtmlService.createHtmlOutput('Success!');
  } else {
    return HtmlService.createHtmlOutput('Denied.');
  }
}


// Access the Redirect URI //

function logRedirectUri() {
  Logger.log(OAuth2.getRedirectUri());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are using `QUARTERLY_NONE_MET` as `gov-test-scenario` which is only used for retrieving VAT obligations.

From the documentation of submitting VAT return of period, these are the valid values.

```
INVALID_VRN, INVALID_PERIODKEY, INVALID_PAYLOAD, DUPLICATE_SUBMISSION, TAX_PERIOD_NOT_ENDED, INSOLVENT_TRADER
```

Try using the listed values instead to see if the same error still occurs.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, I've removed the "gov-test-scenario" code and unfortunately it's returning this error message: "code": "INVALID_SCOPE", "message": "Can not access the required resource